.NET MAUI Hybrid Blazor Copy to Clipboard
I've found a few resources on how to copy to clipboard within MAUI Native, plus within Blazor Server, but I'm wondering how can you get copy to clipboard working on a Blazor page within a .NET MAUI Hybrid app?
Here's a resource from MS on native: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/clipboard?view=net-maui-8.0

Did you try to use the maui clipboard directly? And what problem did you met?

You can jsut use the Maui ClipBoard api to do that:
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Copy">Copy</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Paste">Paste</button>
<InputText @bind-Value="@value"/>
@code{
    public string value;
    public async void Copy()
    {
        await Clipboard.Default.SetTextAsync("Copy to Click");
    }
    public async void Paste()
    {
        value = await Clipboard.Default.GetTextAsync();
    }
}

Or you can call the javascript to do that:
@inject IJSRuntime js;
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Copy">Copy</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Paste">Paste</button>
<InputText @bind-Value="@value" />

@code {
    public string value;
    public async void Copy()
    {
        js.InvokeVoidAsync("navigator.clipboard.writeText", "Copy to clipboard");
    }
    public async void Paste()
    {
        //value = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("navigator.clipboard.readText");
        // this can't work for android because the navigator.clipboard.readText is not compatible with the Android WebView
    }
}

Note: The javascript paste will crash on the Android, so using the .net maui clipboard api is better.
